Infinite intersection equals a singlet: some clarifications
I have some troubles in understanding this, which perhaps is trivial but I hope for some more deep explanation (whether they be on the question itself or on my way to reason about this).
Consider this set
$$A = \bigcap_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \left[1-\frac{1}{n}, 2n \right]$$
Now if we start to build the set, this is just
$$A = [0, 2] \cap \left[\frac{1}{2}, 4\right] \cap \left[\frac{3}{2}, 6\right] \cap \ldots$$
And as $n\to +\infty$ we arrive at $\ldots \cap (1, +\infty)$.
Now since we ask for the intersection, we need to find what elements belong to every interval. For what I can see, there is no element which lies in every interval, so in my opinion, rather intuitively, I would conclude $A = \emptyset$.
My professor's notes instead say that $A = \{1\}$.
I would understand why this. The element $1$ doesn't belong to $A$, we "arrive at it when $n \to +\infty$, hence it's a limiting case. I cannot even say it's a boundary point for $A$.
Can you please tell me where I'm wrong? Thank you!
EDIT
I'm an idiot.
Thanks to David Gao. Still I don't get why $A$ is $\{ 1 \}$ and not, hence, $[1, 2]$...

… why do you think $1$ is not in $A$? $1 \in [1 - \frac{1}{n}, 2n]$ for every $n$, so $1$ is in the intersection of all these intervals, namely $A$. What exactly is your confusion regarding this?

@DavidGao Well, apparently I'm an idiot :D you're right. Ok, but then I still don't understand why $A = {1}$. With what you told me, and analysing it more carefully, every number in $[1, 2]$ belongs to $A$, hence $A$ must be equal to $[1, 2]$, right?

$A = [1, 2]$, yes. The notes from your professor are wrong on that.

Note that where you have $3/2$, you should have $2/3$.
